# Using Google Analytics to check when a redirect is triggering

Tags: javascript, php, google-analytics

I have a redirect, written in php that allows be to trigger a particular search in my gmail.  I'm interested to see how often I trigger the search and it seemed obvious to me to add Google Analytics tracking code to it so that my normal analytics would track how often the redirect triggered for me.  However, analtics is telling me that the page is never triggered, even though I might use it half a dosen times in the day.  What am I doing wrong?

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m
)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-43886525-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

var d = new Date()
var days=<?
$url = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; // gives /test/test/ from http://example.org/tes
t/test/
echo substr("$url",6); 
echo "\n";
?>-1

d.setTime(d.getTime()-86400*1000);
var daysBack=d.getDate()-days;
window.location = "https://mail.google.com/mail/?shva=1#search/in%3Ainbox+before
%3A"+(d.getYear()+1900)+"%2F"+(d.getMonth()+1)+"%2F"+daysBack;
//-->
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your hits are not being captured because your redirect is happening before Google Analytics has a chance to load.

The code you're using to load Google Analytics does so asynchronously. That means that it takes a bit of time before the Google Analytics code is able to actually send data to the GA back-end.

At the point in your code that you call `window.location = ...`, there is absolutely no way the Google Analytics library has had a chance to download, execute, and send the hit before your redirect occurs. And as soon as you leave the current page, all existing code stops executing; thus your hits are never sent.

If you want to ensure that your GA hits are sent before you redirect you'll need to use the [hitCallback](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced#hitCallback) function.

From your code above, move the line that says `ga('send', 'pageview')` after the rest of your code, and combine it with your redirect like so:

```
ga('send', 'pageview', {
  hitCallback: function() {
    // This code will run once the pageview has been successfully sent to GA.
    window.location = "https://mail.google.com/..."
  }
});
```

This will ensure that your redirect doesn't happen until after your page is tracked.

Comment: Perfect! I suspected the asynchronously problem, but had never seen the hitCallback idiom.

Answer (score 1):

How does you redirecting set-up?

**Example:**
if this code is set-up before you analytic code then it would not be captured by Google Analytic because you not letting your PHP run fully

```
header('Location: index.php');
```

Comment: Sidenote: The syntax Vilvas is `header("Location: http://www.example.com");` or `header('Location: http://www.example.com');` - your first quote is misplaced. ;)